# Given an homomorphism of commutative rings $A$ and $B$, show that an ideal $U$ in $A$ is prime/maximal in $A$ if an ideal $J$ in $B$ is.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Given $\varphi : A \to B$ a commutative rings homomorphism, $J$ an ideal in $B$, an element $b \in B \setminus J$ and $U=\{ x \in A : \varphi(x)b \in J \}$, show that:

1. If $J$ is a prime ideal in $B$, then $U$ is a prime ideal in $A$.
2. If $J$ is a maximal ideal in $B$, then $U$ is  a maximal ideal in $A$.

Since each question relies on the fact that $U$ is an ideal, I'll prove that first.

We have that $0_A \in U$, because $\varphi(0_A)b=0_Bb=0_B$ and, since $J$ is an ideal in $B$, $0_B \in J$.

For each $u, v \in U$ and for each $y \in A$, we have:

- $u-v \in U$

$\varphi(u-v)b=(\varphi(u)-\varphi(v))b=\varphi(u)b-\varphi(v)b$

Since $\varphi(u)b, \varphi(v)b \in J$ and $J$ is an ideal, it follows that $\varphi(u)b-\varphi(v)b \in J$, which means $u-v \in U$.

- $uy \in U$

$\varphi(uy)b=\varphi(u)\varphi(y)b=(\varphi(u)b)\varphi(y)$

As $\varphi(u)b \in J$, it follows, for the properties of $J$ as an ideal, that $(\varphi(u)b)\varphi(y) \in J$, that is $uy \in U$.

This proves that $U$ is an ideal in $A$.

---

### 1.

Let $c, d \in A$ such that $cd \in U$.

This means that $\varphi(cd)b \in J$, by hypothesis $J$ is a prime ideal, so we have: $\varphi(cd) \in J$ or $b \in J$.

Since $b$ is chosen in $B \setminus J$, it has to be $\varphi(cd) \in J$. This can be rewritten as:

$\varphi(cd)=\varphi(c)\varphi(d)$

As we observed before, it has to be: $\varphi(c) \in J$ or $\varphi(d) \in J$. Let's suppose $\varphi(c) \in J$. This allows us to write $\varphi(c)b \in J$, which means $c \in U$.

It follows that $U$ is a prime ideal in $A$, and of course the choice of $\varphi(c) \in J$ or $\varphi(d) \in J$ makes no difference, since we are working with commutative rings.

Now, I want to ask you whether my proofs up to this point are correct and if you could give some help with the second part, since I don't know how to exploit the fact that $J$ is maximal to prove that $U$ is maximal, too.

Comment: Where is this problem from? Unless, I've misread something, I don't think claim #2 is true. If we take $b = 1$, then $U = \varphi^{-1}(J)$, which is not necessarily maximal just because $J$ is. (For example, take $\varphi$ to be the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$, and $J = \{0\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: What should be true (among other things), instead of your second item, is that the inverse image of a maximal ideal under a map between finitely generated algebras over an algebraically closed field is a maximal ideal.

Comment: In case $J$ is prime, then $U$ is just the preimage $\varphi^{-1}(J)$. Fact 1 is ok but as it is said above, Fact 2 is wrong

Comment: It is from a written exam, my professor gave in 2016, if it's wrong maybe he intended it as "Prove or Disprove". But he wrote it the same way I did, except I translated it from Italian. Thank you all for the comments!